# How to properly run a Python script from PHP

Tags: php, python, permissions, shell-exec

I have a PHP script that unzips an archive containing Python scripts into a directory, str_replaces some things inside the script, shell_exec's the script, and then unlinks the script.

I have no problems unzipping the archive or chmodding the contents to 0755. I can execute the generated scripts through terminal and they perform as expected, but with PHP nothing happens!

I have tried specifying absolute paths for Python in my shell_exec and in a shebang within the Python file to no avail. There appear to be no syntax errors or unmet dependencies. I've tried this with all affected directories at chmod 0777 to no avail either. The section of relevant code is as follows...

```php
if (in_array($oldExtension,$allowed)) { 
    list($Width, $Height) = getimagesize($CUD);
    $EXFreshScript = $InstLoc.'/Applications/document-scanner-master.zip';
    $EXTempScript = $InstLoc.'/DATA/'.$UserID.'/TEMPSCRIPTS';
    mkdir($EXTempScript);
    chmod($EXTempScript, 0777);
    $ExtractScripts = shell_exec('unzip '.$EXFreshScript.' -d '.$EXTempScript);
    chmod($EXTempScript.'/document-scanner', 0777);
    $TempScript = $EXTempScript.'/document-scanner/scan.py';
    chmod($EXTempScript.'/document-scanner', 0777);
    $TempScriptGlob = glob($TempScript);
    foreach ($TempScriptGlob as $TSG) {
    chmod($TSG, 0777); }
    chmod($EXTempScript.'/document-scanner/pyimagesearch', 0777);
    $TempScript1 = $EXTempScript.'/document-scanner/pyimagesearch';
    $TempScriptGlob = glob($TempScript1);
    foreach ($TempScriptGlob as $TSG) {
        chmod($TSG, 0777);
    }
    $OutputDoc = $InstLoc.'/DATA/'.$UserID.'/DOCSCANTEMP.jpg';
    $Code = 'DOCSCANTEMP.jpg';
    $newCode = $InstLoc.'/DATA/'.$UserID.'/DOCSCANTEMP.jpg'; 
    $ScriptData = file_get_contents($TempScript);
    $SwapCode = str_replace($Code, $newCode, $ScriptData);
    $WriteCode = file_put_contents($TempScript, $SwapCode);
    $txt = ('OP-Act: Modified the code of '.$TempScript.' with '.$Width.', '.$Height.' on '.$Time.'.');
    $LogFile = file_put_contents($SesLogDir.'/'.$Date.'.txt', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND);
    $txt = ('OP-Act: Executing! '.$TempScript.' on '.$Time.'.');
    $LogFile = file_put_contents($SesLogDir.'/'.$Date.'.txt', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND);
    chmod($TempScript, 0777);
    shell_exec('python '.$TempScript.' -i '.$CTD);
    $txt = ('OP-Act: Execute complete! '.$TempScript.' was executed  on '.$Time.'.');
    $LogFile = file_put_contents($SesLogDir.'/'.$Date.'.txt', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND);
}
```

If anyone has any ideas I'd greatly appreciate it. The script this came from is over 650 lines long and I've got my issue narrowed down to this. Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried if php can execute any script at all? On some servers, shell_exec is disabled. Does PHP show any errors?

Comment: PHP can perform shell_exec. I proved that out elsewhere in the script, and even in this section of code the shell_exec that unzips the archive works fine. The only error that is returned one that I programmed to be thrown in the event that the Python script did not output a file. The rest of the project can be found at https://github.com/zelon88/HRCloud2.

Answer (score 0):

I'll focus on this line:

```
shell_exec('python '.$TempScript.' -i '.$CTD);
```

1. Seems like `$CTD` is not defined.
2. Don't use `-i` flag because it enforces python prompt.
3. Try to use `exec()` instead for better debugging.

If it won't help you, let me know what it outputs.

```
$return = NULL;
$output = [];
exec('python '.$TempScript, $output, $return);
var_dump($return);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't seem to get any errors indicating that $CTD is defined. It does get mentioned earlier in the script. I entered the code you gave me and changed the shell_exec to exec. I still have to try removing the -i, but the problem with that is that it's an argument for my Python script that specified the input file. I will try removing that next. The output for the code you gave me is...   int(1) array(0) { }     But I also get an error from the script that the output file was not generated.

Comment: You got return code 1. It means that python script ended with error, but output is empty. Is there any exception catching in python script which suppress errors? Also, there's too much noise here. Can you please replicate your code sample with smallest amount of code possible? Try to include your python script too.